# What is the difference between the two FactType interfaces?

Tags: drools, drools-guvnor

I'm using Drools 5.3.5 and a declarative Fact Model defined in guvnor. I have both `drools-core-5.3.5.Final.jar` and `knowledge-api-5.3.5.Final.jar` on the classpath of the application interacting with the rules engine.

Each of these JARs contains an interface called FactType:

```
drools-core-5.3.5.Final.jar   -> org.drools.rule.FactType  
knowledge-api-5.3.5.Final.jar -> org.drools.definition.type.FactType
```

I see that `org.drools.KnowledgeBase.getFactType()` returns `org.drools.definition.type.FactType` objects; so what is `org.drools.rule.FactType` used for? Should my code always make use of the knowledge-api FactType?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible that org.drools.rule.FactType is some trash that's been left over after some refactoring. A grep for the full class name doesn't return a hit. (I think I've seen other duplicates but forgive me for not searching for them.)

The -api- jar evolved during 5.x as an intent to collect all of the stable IFs in one jar.

By all means: stick with the classes you find in the "stable" javadoc, i.e., `org.drools.definition.type.FactType`. This is the only way (at least, the best effort) to maintain compatibility when upgrading to later versions.